# Python: sort this dictionary (dict in dict)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

```
d = { 'a':{'k':1, 'b':'whatever'},  'b':{'k':2, 'b':'sort by k'} }
```

Want to sort this dictionary by k as descending order, in python.

Little tricky, please help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`dict`s are unordered. So there is no way to sort them directly, but if you are 
willing to convert the `dict` into a list of (key,value)-tuples, then you could do this:

```
In [9]: d
Out[9]: {'a': {'b': 'whatever', 'k': 1}, 'b': {'b': 'sort by k', 'k': 2}}

In [15]: sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x: x[1]['k'],reverse=True)
Out[15]: [('b', {'b': 'sort by k', 'k': 2}), ('a', {'b': 'whatever', 'k': 1})]
```

This [excellent mini-howto](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#KeyFunctions) explains the use of the `key` parameter.

Comment: Can you please explain `x[1]['k']`? I understand the ['k'] part, but what is x[1]?

Comment: it says list object is not callable?

Comment: @A: `dict.items()` returns a list of 2-tuples of (key, value).

Comment: @A A: As `sorted` sorts `d.items()`, `x` is set to each element of `d.items()`. So `x` might equal the 2-tuple `('b', {'b': 'sort by k', 'k': 2})`, for example. `x[1]` is the second element, `{'b': 'sort by k', 'k': 2}`, and `x[1]['k']` is therefore (in this case) 2.

Comment: Do we need to import anything to do this? Can we do this in python 2.6? It doesn't work for me. 'list' object is not callabe.

Comment: @user, You do not need to import anything. I suggest you use copy and paste instead of retyping it

Comment: @user469652: You possibly have a variable with the name `sorted` which shadows the built-in function `sorted()`.

Answer (score 5):

> Use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), if you use python 2.7 or later.

Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember the order that items were inserted. When iterating over an ordered dictionary, the items are returned in the order their keys were first added.

From the example

```
>>> # regular unsorted dictionary
>>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

>>> # dictionary sorted by key
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
```

For trying to achieve something of the same effect for python 2.4 or lower, see:

- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693/

> **A drop-in substitute for Py2.7's new collections.OrderedDict that works in Python 2.4-2.6.**

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict

Comment: @user469652 : I have added the link to pypi or recipe that emulates it and will work with python 2.6

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import *

d = { 'a':{'k':1, 'b':'whatever'},  'b':{'k':2, 'b':'sort by k'} }
sorted_d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: getitem(x[1], 'k')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are not "sorted". That isn't a meaningful concept. The keys and values are not, conceptually, in any "order" at all, so you can't change what order they're in.

Comment: Yes, but we can convert it into other sequence type and sort it and turn it back to dictionary again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dictionary (data) with sub-dictionaries (d1 and d2) containing a value (v) and priority (p), if you wanted to sort the dictionary for the intention of iterating over it then then you can do this:

```
data = { "d1": { "v": "hello", "p": 3}, "d2": {"v": "hi again", "p": 1},}

for item in sorted(data.keys(), key=lambda x: data[x]['p']):
    print item
```