# sort sub-dicts in a dict by value of the sub-dict

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

this is my json:

```
{"data": [{"L": "Leinster"}, {"RN": "Roscommon"}, {"G": "Galway"}, {"LS": "Laois"}, {"LD": "Longford"}, {"OY": "Offaly"}, {"KK": "Kilkenny"}, {"SO": "Sligo"}, {"C": "Connaught"}, {"CO": "Cork"}, {"M": "Munster"}, {"WD": "Waterford"}, {"CE": "Clare"}]}
```

I want to sort so that the dict will be ordered by the 'abc' of the value like:

```
  {"data": [ {"CE": "Clare"},{"C": "Connaught"}, {"CO": "Cork"}, {"G": "Galway"},{"KK": "Kilkenny"}, {"LS": "Laois"},{"L": "Leinster"}, {"LD": "Longford"}, {"M": "Munster"},{"OY": "Offaly"}, {"RN": "Roscommon"}, {"SO": "Sligo"}, {"WD": "Waterford"} ]}
```

some ideas? tried this [Python: sort this dictionary (dict in dict)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331892/python-sort-this-dictionary-dict-in-dict)
 but this is sorting values. not the values in the dict.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Python 2

```
>>> d = {'data': [{'L': 'Leinster'}, {'RN': 'Roscommon'}, {'G': 'Galway'}, {'LS': 'Laois'}, {'LD': 'Longford'}, {'OY': 'Offaly'}, {'KK': 'Kilkenny'}, {'SO': 'Sligo'}, {'C': 'Connaught'}, {'CO': 'Cork'}, {'M': 'Munster'}, {'WD': 'Waterford'}, {'CE': 'Clare'}]}
>>> dict((k,sorted(v,key=dict.values)) for k,v in d.iteritems())
{'data': [{'CE': 'Clare'}, {'C': 'Connaught'}, {'CO': 'Cork'}, {'G': 'Galway'}, {'KK': 'Kilkenny'}, {'LS': 'Laois'}, {'L': 'Leinster'}, {'LD': 'Longford'}, {'M': 'Munster'}, {'OY': 'Offaly'}, {'RN': 'Roscommon'}, {'SO': 'Sligo'}, {'WD': 'Waterford'}]}
```

Here is a python 3 solution, It would be great to know if there was something better than this since I don't like it much.

```
>>> {k:sorted(v,key=lambda x: tuple(x.values())) for k,v in d.items()}
{'data': [{'CE': 'Clare'}, {'C': 'Connaught'}, {'CO': 'Cork'}, {'G': 'Galway'}, {'KK': 'Kilkenny'}, {'LS': 'Laois'}, {'L': 'Leinster'}, {'LD': 'Longford'}, {'M': 'Munster'}, {'OY': 'Offaly'}, {'RN': 'Roscommon'}, {'SO': 'Sligo'}, {'WD': 'Waterford'}]}
```

Comment: +1, not gonna post mine now even though it's a little different it's no better :^)

Answer (score 1):

or may be you can simply do

**Updated** for sort by values

```
In [41]: r={"data": [{"L": "Leinster"}, {"RN": "Roscommon"}, {"G": "Galway"}, {"LS": "Laois"}, {"LD": "Longford"}, {"OY": "Offaly"}, {"KK": "Kilkenny"}, {"SO": "Sligo"}, {"C": "Connaught"}, {"CO": "Cork"}, {"M": "Munster"}, {"WD": "Waterford"}, {"CE": "Clare"}]}

In [42]: for v in r.itervalues():
....:     v.sort(key=dict.values)
....: 

In [43]: r
Out[43]:  
{'data': [{'CE': 'Clare'},
      {'C': 'Connaught'},
      {'CO': 'Cork'},
      {'G': 'Galway'},
      {'KK': 'Kilkenny'},
      {'LS': 'Laois'},
      {'L': 'Leinster'},
      {'LD': 'Longford'},
      {'M': 'Munster'},
      {'OY': 'Offaly'},
      {'RN': 'Roscommon'},
      {'SO': 'Sligo'},
      {'WD': 'Waterford'}]}
```

Comment: Could be fixed by replacing `v.sort()` with `v.sort(key=dict.values)`.

Comment: kk..if you need to sort by values of inside dict

Comment: I like this because it sorts the lists in place rather than creating a new dict and its much more elegant than my hacky solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution, because the more the merrier!

```
>>> r={"data": [{"L": "Leinster"}, {"RN": "Roscommon"}, {"G": "Galway"}, {"LS": "Laois"}, {"LD": "Longford"}, {"OY": "Offaly"}, {"KK": "Kilkenny"}, {"SO": "Sligo"}, {"C": "Connaught"}, {"CO": "Cork"}, {"M": "Munster"}, {"WD": "Waterford"}, {"CE": "Clare"}]}
>>>
>>> map(functools.partial(list.sort, key=dict.values), r.itervalues())
[None]
>>>
>>> r
{'data': [{'CE': 'Clare'}, {'C': 'Connaught'}, {'CO': 'Cork'}, {'G': 'Galway'}, {'KK': 'Kilkenny'}, {'LS': 'Laois'}, {'L': 'Leinster'}, {'LD': 'Longford'}, {'M': 'Munster'}, {'OY': 'Offaly'}, {'RN': 'Roscommon'}, {'SO': 'Sligo'}, {'WD': 'Waterford'}]}
```